# Using a shell script involving echo to add student header to C++ files: Replaces \n with actual newline, any way to change behavior?

Tags: shell, echo, cat

I'm taking a C++ course that requires a student header at the top of every submitted file. Typing it or yank/paste-ing is *so* tedious, I've been working on a script to just add it for me. I've got something that works for me so far, but I just noticed that every `\n` in any string in the files that it operates on are replaced with an actual newline. I'm guessing this is either a result of the use of `cat` or `echo` in the script, and I'm trying to figure out how to avoid that.

The manpage for `echo` says that the default behavior is to ignore backslash escapes, but I'm not entirely sure how that relates to what I'm trying to do.

My script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="Joseph Morgan"
CLASS="CISP 400 MoWe 3:00pm"
ASSIGNMENT=$1
DATE=$(date -I)

if [[ $# -eq 0 ]] ; then
    echo 'Argument required:'
    echo 'Usage: SOME_PROJECT_NAME [Adds project name to header] | d [Deletes header]'
    exit 0
fi

if [ $1 == "d" ] ; then
    echo 'Deleting header - Be careful! If no header is present, the first five lines of your files will be deleted'
    read -p "Are you sure? (y/n)" -n 1 -r
    echo
    if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
    then
        for f in ./*.cpp ;
        do
            echo "$(tail -n +6 $f)" > $f
        done
        for f in ./*.h ;
        do
            echo "$(tail -n +6 $f)" > $f
        done
    fi
    exit 0
fi

for f in ./*.cpp ;
do
    echo -e "// $NAME\n// $CLASS\n// $ASSIGNMENT\n// $DATE\n\n$(cat $f)" > $f
done

for f in ./*.h ; 
do
    echo -e "// $NAME\n// $CLASS\n// $ASSIGNMENT\n// $DATE\n\n$(cat $f)" > $f
done
```

If there is another way entirely to accomplish this, feel free to suggest it. I'm much more interested in learning here, the script was just for fun/education so it's not incredibly important.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `-e` parameter given to echo(1) command, which makes it interpret `\n` as a new line. Delete that `-e` and it will work. I mean, you *need* that -e, when you write your own headers, but you should move the `$(cat $f)` outside of the "echo -e". For example, in two lines:

```
echo -e "// $NAME\n// $CLASS\n// $ASSIGNMENT\n// $DATE\n\n" > $f
echo "$(cat $f)" >> $f    # notice the double angle >>
```

BUT BEWARE, that would erase your file before reading it. Even here there is a problem:

> echo "$(tail -n +6 $f)" > $f

because it could erase (empty) the "$f" file before reading it. You could do instead:

```
newcontent=$(tail -n +6 $f)
echo "$newcontent" > $f
```

So, to add your headers, use two distinct echoes, but read the file before writing in it:

```
newcontent="$(cat $f)"
echo -e "// $NAME\n// $CLASS\n// $ASSIGNMENT\n// $DATE\n\n" > $f
echo "$newcontent" >> $f    # notice the double angle >>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I like it.

What do the double angles do in this context?

Comment: @JosephMorgan Correct, it's append. Beware of referencing the same file in the same command(s) (even via pipes)... best wishes and cheers.